# Use mean or the median in the following situations? Why?

Tags: statistics

a) Middle town is considering imposing an income tax on citizens. The city government wants to know the average income of citizens so that it can estimate the total income base?

b) In a study of the standard of living of typical families in Middletown, a sociologist estimates the average family income in that city?

My answers are:
a) median 
b) mean

However, I am not quite sure how to explain why. I guess is it because for question (b), asking for "typical families in the Middletown" which mean the families are similar to each other, so we can use mean for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

When we're dealing with incomes, we tend to see a fairly skewed distribution. Many people have low incomes, but then some people have very very high incomes, so the mean is always above the median.

I think the generally correct answer would be the opposite to what you propose. In terms of the total income tax base, the revenues from income taxes will depend more on what the mean family earns than the median. The reason for this is that the super wealthy families will pay massive income tax bills. Using the median would suggest it doesn't matter exactly how wealthy the wealthiest families are, where obviously that does for tax purposes.

In terms of the sociologist looking at standard of living, the median is a much better indicator. The reason is that if the top 10% of the distribution doubles their income, and everybody else's income stays the same, the mean would go up a lot, suggesting that living standards had improved for the typical family, even though the typical family's income didn't change. Therefore, using the median, which is just the family at the 50th percentile of the distribution, is a better indicator of how a *middle class* family is doing.